Unconnected tf trees to obtain IMU frame movements relative global frame in rviz (Realsense D435i)
I am trying to obtain the position and movements of the IMU within a Realsense D435i camera from a .bag file.
I am using the command
roslaunch realsense2_camera opensource_tracking.launch offline:=true 

and I have modified opensource_tracking.launch so that it displays the global frame as map set at (0 0 0 0 0 0) since in my ROS system no global frame is set.
Like this:
...opensource_tracking.launch code
 <!-- Static transform from map to camera_link -->
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_camera_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map camera_link" />

<!-- Static transform from camera_link to camera_imu_optical_frame -->
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_link_to_camera_imu_optical_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 camera_link camera_imu_optical_frame" />
</launch>

The problem is that by doing so I get the error:
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher] For frame [camera_imu_optical_frame]:
No transform to fixed frame [map]. TF error: [Could not find a connection between 'map' and
'camera_imu_optical_frame' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.]

How can I connect map with camera_imu_optical_frame so that I can see the movements made by the camera frame relative to the global frame map?
This is the tf tree i get:


There can only be one root on the tf tree so you can try to have the trasform form map to odom and then odom to both camera link and camera_imu_optical_frame


camera_link should be connected to camera_imu_optical_frame (static transform).
I believe you have a node called ImuFilter. That node should publish transform between odom and camera_link.
Create a transform from map to odom as you did in the launch file.

